# Azure DevOps Server 2020 - Installing Search - error not compatible

Tags: azure-devops-server, azure-devops-server-2020

Hi We are running Azure Devops Server 2020 update 1 patch 4. We want to use the Search functionality On a dedicated server). Im following the steps on this site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/install-configure-search?view=azure-devops-2020#secure-search.
I'm getting stuck at the Readiness checks with an error in the log:

> [Error  @14:31:33.683] search plugin with version: '6.2.4.22' is not compatible, supported search plugin version: 6.2.4.18
> [Info   @14:31:33.683] Node returned: Error
> [Error  @14:31:33.683] Elasticsearch plugin: 'AlmSearchPlugin' with version: '6.2.4.22' is not supported. Ensure that your remote Search server has been updated to the latest version prior to configuring Search.
> [Info   @14:31:33.683] Completed Service Not Installed: Error

When going to through the details of the [patch 4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2020u1?view=azure-devops#azure-devops-server-202011-patch-4-release-date-january-26-2022) I read that you should check the registry value and set the Version to 5.4.1. For me after the installation it was set to 6.2.4.1.
I gave it a try by setting it to 5.4.1 and run the command:

> .\Configure-TFSSearch.ps1 -Operation update -verbose

Unfortunately after this the value was again set to 6.2.4.1 and also the readiness checks gave the same results.

This error was also reported on the [blog-page about this patch](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/azure-devops-server-and-team-foundation-server-patches/). But there was not really an answer, but tweaking some files coming from the installation folder (see comment Edwin Siebes; feb 1st). Is this really the solution? Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contact with Microsoft support I got a new dll: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.dll which fixed the problem.

This was a private patch they said they going to make it public.